# Implementing "Donate" functionality

Tags: java, android

I have created a free Android app, and i want to implement "donate" functionality, but have no idea how to do it? Can someone help me with that? Some tutorial or something like that? How to implement it for countries not supported bu PayPal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tutorial on implementing PayPal with your Android app [here](https://personal.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/mobile_android).  Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001148/donate-via-in-app-billing) out for why it's difficult to implement in-app billing for an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to implement In-App Billing, it seems like the simplest way to me. Here's the link: [In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work in this case because there is no "selling of virtual goods" here. It is donation, and using In-App Billing for it, makes it a bit inconvenient for users..