# PayPal MPL - how to let user choose amount?

Tags: android, paypal

I am currently working on implementing a 'Donation' option in my app and have decided to go with PayPal (see: [Donate via in-app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001148/donate-via-in-app-billing))

After reading the docs etc, decided to go with the PayPal Mobile Payment Libraries (MPL). Everything seems to be working for me (transactions are being shown in the sandbox etc)

However, I've currently just hard-coded the donation amount to $5. I was wondering if there is a nice way of letting the user choose the amount they want to donate.

The only "solution" I can find at the moment is to display a dialog first to ask the user for a donation amount - but this just feels ugly. Hoping that there is a nicer way to accomplish this!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why is it ugly to display a dialog? It's a very common way to prompt the user to enter an amount.

You can set it to $5 by default and also add radio buttons to choose between fixed amounts. Add some text ("any donations are welcome, feel free to choose the amount, ...") so you won't have just a button and a text field. The goal is just to make a "pretty" dialog.

If you want to let your users choose the amount, you don't really have other choices.

Comment: It feels 'ugly' to me because the payment is PayPal style, but the initial dialog is more Android style. So in a way, despite being the one action (donating) the user will see two fairly different interfaces.